# UDP connection from different locations

Tags: java, udp

If I want to do UDP file transfer from one PC to another on separate networks, which IP address will my PC be connecting to (considering I know it ahead of time), and how can I find it? I can find the public IP, but several PCs on the same network have the same public IP.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a traceroute from the different PCs and seeing what the originating IP is.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that computer A wants to make a UDP connection to computer B.

A will then have to use B's public IP that B's network shares.

For that to work, B's network has to be aware of it: on its router (that masks private IP) set port forwarding for the desired UDP number to the computer B (to its private IP).

In order to do what previous paragraph says, you will need admin access to that router or be able to ask whoever is the admin to do the port forwarding for you - you'll just need to tell them which UDP port and to which computer (B).